# webview running in the background

Tags: android, webview

I am writing a simple app for android, basically it launches a website via webview.  When I run this app, it continues consuming data even while in the background. It is small (a couple of bytes every 10 minutes)  is there a way to prevent this data consumption? in other words to tell webview to take a nap an stop consuming data, and wake up (refresh the page) when the app is on the foreground.

Comment: How can you tell that it is using data while the device is asleep? And are you certain that it is actually your application that is using data, and not something else present on the device?

Comment: I downloaded a detailed network traffic/data manager. It shows traffic usage by app.  I'm basically running a php 'Hello World' which is why I'm baffled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were other processes running within the app (javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can also call onPause() on the webView to stop javascript on it.